# Animating translateZ makes rotateY mirrored

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm working on something that involves 3 deck of cards.

And I want to be able to move cards from the far most deck to the middle deck and as a final step to the first deck.

Moving and rotating works fine, BUT if I add a translateZ so make the "side decks" look like they are behind the middle deck for some reason my rotation get mirrored when going from middle deck to left most deck.

I have tried changing the Z axis, changing between positive and negative values, but I get the same result regardless.

I have made a simplified jsfiddle to show what I mean.

HTML

```
<div class="cards">
  <div class="next-deck">
   <div class="card card-next">
     <div class="card-front">
     front
     </div>
     <div class="card-back">
       back
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cards {
      width:  650px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: relative;
      height: 200px;
      perspective: 800px;
    }

    .card {
      width: 75px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 50px;
      transition: all ease 1s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translateZ(-100px);
    }

    .card-active {
        transform: translateX(-50%) rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    .card-discarded {
        transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-360deg) translateZ(-100px);
    }

    .card-front, .card-back{
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .card-front{
      background: red;
    }

    .card-back{
      background: green;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
```

Complete js fiddle with JS https://jsfiddle.net/58Lab2tf/41/

Comment: `for some reason my rotation get mirrored` ? can you elaborate this

Comment: If you test the jsfiddle you will notice that the first time you click the card it animates correctly, but the second time the rotation is in the opposite direction

Comment: use rotateY(0) in the second transform

Comment: That's the problem, it makes no difference. Using 0 SHOULD work, but for some reason it does not, and I can't figure out why

Comment: i tried and it's working

Comment: Could you please update jsfiddle and post link because I can not get it to work?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cz8tznet/1/ here is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167268/discussion-between-jonathan-andersson-and-temani-afif).